# Oracle pivot rows with the same ID

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a question and can be solved with a pivot but am unable to get a solution. Please help me to do that.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( CUST_ID, RATE ) AS
  SELECT 1, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 600 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 800 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 200 FROM DUAL;
```

**Required output**

```
CUST_ID RATE CUST_ID RATE CUST_ID RATE CUST_ID RATE CUST_ID RATE CUST_ID RATE
------- ---- ------- ---- ------- ---- ------- ---- ------- ---- ------- ----
1       100  2       100  3       300  4       200  5       500  6       800  
1       200                            4       600               6       200
```

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Please don't use images or image links. Paste the tables as text instead. Then, what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: An SQL query selects a before-known number of columns. Do you know that there will always be exactly 6 cust_id? That doesn't seem likely. So this isn't really a task for SQL. With SQL you'd select the data. Use your app or Webpage to care about how to display this data in a grid.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Query:

```
SELECT "1_CUST_ID" AS CUST_ID1,
       "1_RATE"    AS RATE1,
       "2_CUST_ID" AS CUST_ID2,
       "2_RATE"    AS RATE2,
       "3_CUST_ID" AS CUST_ID3,
       "3_RATE"    AS RATE3,
       "4_CUST_ID" AS CUST_ID4,
       "4_RATE"    AS RATE4,
       "5_CUST_ID" AS CUST_ID5,
       "5_RATE"    AS RATE5,
       "6_CUST_ID" AS CUST_ID6,
       "6_RATE"    AS RATE6
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
PIVOT (
  MAX( cust_id ) AS cust_id,
  MAX( rate ) AS rate
  FOR cust_id IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 )
)
```

Output:

```
CUST_ID1 RATE1 CUST_ID2 RATE2 CUST_ID3 RATE3 CUST_ID4 RATE4 CUST_ID5 RATE5 CUST_ID6 RATE6
-------- ----- -------- ----- -------- ----- -------- ----- -------- ----- -------- ----- 
1        100   2        100   3        300   4        200   5        500   6        800  
1        200                                 4        600                  6        200
```

*(Note: you have no way of ordering the rows per customer id and queries are not guaranteed to be deterministic in their ordering so you may find that values switch which row they are in if, for example, you have row movement enabled on your table.)*